# What USB NAS adapter allows one to mount its attached hard drive and access it locally and remotely via the internet?

Tags: nas

My question is, what NAS USB adapter that one can connect to an external SATA hard drive allows one to view files on the NAS in the local network as well as from outside through the internet?

It needs to allow the hard drive to be mounted on computers such that the drive will transfer files at a faster rate when the computers are in the local network and possibly at a slower rate when they're outside and accessing through the internet. Also cost should be as minimal as possible.

Comment: I'd quite like to find one of these too.  Business case: We have a tape drive that only seems to be happy saving logfiles to a USB stick.  I'd like a thing that could pretend to be a USB mass storage device, but also present a filesystem over IP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by this 'NAS USB adapter' you mention, I totally understand why you may be interested in *either* a SATA-to-USB adapter *or* a SATA-to-Ethernet/NAS-protocols adapter but I don't know how a USB adapter would form part of a NAS, it's a point-to-point interface not a shared one.

Either way if your question really relates to if there's a difference between a NAS box of any kind that works internally versus one that works externally then I can answer that - there really is no difference. If a device presents itself using NAS protocols (say NFS or CIFS/SMB) then where the client is is irrelevant, it's IP-based so the client could be right next to the device on the same network or across the other side of the planet. What you *would* care about is what's doing the firewalling and access control, that would be of much more significant concern to me.

Comment: Next time, please explain new users how to migrate questions (or just leave it) – that way [we won't get duplicates](http://superuser.com/questions/458581/what-usb-nas-adapter-allows-ones-to-mount-its-attached-hard-drive-and-access-it?lq=1) (see the last paragraph). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, [This monolith](http://www.lacie.com/products/product.htm?id=10451) from LaCie appears to have both USB connectivity *AND* Ethernet.. So it might do what I want, but possibly not what you want.. Or it might.  It's not entirely clear from their website whether it does NAS and DAS type access at the same time.

Comment: It does seem to accomplish this. However we're looking for an an adapter we can use with external hard drives (they're actually internal hard drives in an enclosure due to the fact that it costs less to go down that route). The best solution would be a usb adapter that connects the usb based external hard drive to the router and does the things mentioned on the site of this product.